# Set a IP Whitelist For Each User in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I wanted that when users intend to login, if user login from a new IP address , their login failed

and an email containing this content:

> You login form a new IP address (109.169.65.137) Would you like add
>   this IP to you'r allowed IP-LIST"

would be send to their email.

TIP: If user allowed IP_LIST is None, user can login form any IP address

Anyone can guide me to implement this scenario?

I'm using a custom user model

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email   = self.normalize_email(email)
        mobile_number   = mobile_number
        user    = self.model(email=email, mobile_number= mobile_number, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, mobile_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_active') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_active=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username        = None
    email           = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, validators= [validate_email])
    mobile_number   = models.CharField(_("mobile number"), max_length=11, unique = True, validators= [validate_mobile_number])

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile_number']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: First you need to store this IP whitelist for each user, if you are using postgres you could use an array field

Comment: @iain-shelvington then what!?

Answer (score 4):

First you need a field to store the users allowed IPs

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class User(AbstractUser):
    allowed_ips = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20), default=list)
```

Then you need a custom authentication backend to handle rejecting or allowing users to authenticate based on their IP. We can subclass the [`ModelBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend) for this

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class IPBasedModelBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = super().authenticate(request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs)
        if user: # The user passed password validation
            ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
            if not user.allowed_ips:
                user.allowed_ips.append(ip)
                user.save()
                return user
            elif ip not in user.allowed_ips:
                send_email()
                return
            else:
                return user
```

Then you need to change the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['app.backends.IPBasedModelBackend']
```

The email needs to provide a link back to a view in your app that appends the IP to `user.allowed_ips`

```
def add_allowed_ip(request):
    ip = request.GET.get('ip')  # Not sure this would be the most secure place to put it...
    user_id = request.GET.get('user_id')  # Same here...
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    user.allowed_ips.append(ip)
    user.save()
    return redirect('login')
```

Comment: when user use new ip address, user can't login so after that user click on our link and send to my view and add_allowed_ip function call user dosen't authenticate 
then how we can get user_id ? 
user_id = request.GET.get('user_id')

Comment: If you were to use the view given above, you would add `user_id` to the querystring for the URL you send in the template